# Evaluate the curveintegral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Compute the work done by the vector field $$F(x,y)=\left(y,
>  xy-\frac{9y^2}{x}\right),$$ when a particle is moving along the curve
>   $x^2/9-y^2=1,$ from $(3\sqrt{10},3)$ to $(3\sqrt{5},-2).$

The curve goes in negative direction $-\gamma$. I have that $P(x,y)=y, \ Q(x,y)=xy-\frac{9y^2}{x}$ so

$$W=\int_{-\gamma}Pdx+Qdy = -\int_{\gamma}Pdx+Qdy...$$

However, I first need to parameterize my integrand and I'm not sure what I should set $x$ and $y$ to. Is there any systematic method to determine an appropriate parameterization? If it's a circle it's easy by using $x=\cos(t) \ y=\sin(t).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make an answer to avoid talking in the comments, and it would also be too long for a comment.
From [@Salahamam_ Fatima](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/369188/salahamam-fatima)'s idea, we can use the following parametrization:
$$(x,\,y)=(3\cosh(t),\,\sinh(t))$$
Your integral is:
$$\int\vec{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{r}=\int \vec{F}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\int\left(\sinh(t),\,3\sinh(t)\cosh(t)-3\frac{\sinh^2(t)}{\cosh(t)}\right)\cdot(3\sinh(t),\,\cosh(t)) \mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\int\left[3\sinh^2(t)+3\sinh(t)\cosh^2(t)-3\sinh^2(t)\right]\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\int\left[3\sinh(t)\cosh^2(t)\right]\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=3\int\left[\sinh(t)\cosh^2(t)\right]\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=3\left.\frac{\cosh^3(t)}{3}\right|_{\sinh^{-1}(3)}^{\sinh^{-1}(-2)}=\left.\cosh^3(t)\right|_{\sinh^{-1}(3)}^{\sinh^{-1}(-2)}=5\sqrt{5}-10\sqrt{10}$$

Comment: @Parseval What do you think about the answer? There could be problems with the order of the limits, but I think it's good now (so it could be $10\sqrt{10}-5\sqrt{5}$).

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. May I ask what the $T$ is?

Comment: @Parseval what kind of $T$?

Comment: @Parseval Ahh, I see. That's the symbol of the transpose, because I wanted to write "standing" vectors. I'm going to delete it for you.

Comment: The capital t that is here for example: $(x,y)^T.$

Comment: Ah alright, that's ok, I assumed it was just wanted to make sure it was the transpose.

Comment: @Parseval Sorry for the confusion. Was the $5\sqrt{5}-10\sqrt{10}$ correct one?

Comment: Yes, it was. Thank you very much mate! It looks quite straight forward now when I see it. I should probably learn the hyperbolics.

Comment: @Parseval I do also need to thank you for the chance to practice, I've almost forgotten it :D Yes, the hyperbolic functions are quite useful. Do you study physics, or it's just a physics exercise in a math class?

Comment: Yeah, helping others is the best way to learn :) I have another question about a surface integral that I'll post in 5 minutes. I actually study Engineering mathematics and this is multivariable calculus course. You?

Comment: I'm a first-year physics student. I had vector calculus course in the previous semester :) I'm going to have a look at the question.

Comment: Nice, I also study a lot of physics in my program, statics and dynamics. are you good at theese?

Comment: @Botond Thanks. Good night.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Good night.

Answer (score 2):

**hint **

The curve whose cartesian equation is
$$x^2/9-y^2=1$$
can be parametrised by

$$x=3\cosh (t) $$
$$y=\sinh (t) $$

which comes from the identity

$$\cosh^2 (t)-\sinh^2 (t)=1$$

Comment: Okay thanks for this but we are not using hyperbolic functions in this course. Is there a way to do this without them?

Comment: @Parseval $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

Comment: I know, but it's still the definition of the hyperbolic functions.

Comment: Then define your own functions: $\text{myfunction1}(x):=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$, $\text{myfunction2}(x):=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

Comment: Or what about the $\tan^2(x)+1=\sec^2(x)$, so $\sec^2(x)-\tan^2(x)=1$?

Comment: And how would the range for $t$ look like in this case?

Comment: If $y=\tan(t)$ and $x=3\sec(t)$, then the $(3\sqrt{10},3)$ point belongs to $t=\tan^{-1}(3)\approx 1.24905$, and the $(3\sqrt{5},-2)$ to $\tan^{-1}(-2)\approx -1.10715$.

Comment: I meant in the hyperbolic case. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The $(3\sqrt{10},3)$ belongs to $t=\sinh^{-1}(3)=\log(3+\sqrt{10})$ and the $(3\sqrt{5},-2)$ to $t=\sinh^{-1}(-2)=-\log(2+\sqrt{5})$. But you can use the normal trigonometric substitution too, I think.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way to do this. I get the incorrect answer.

Comment: @Parseval What did you get and what's the correct answer?

Comment: I got $\ln(3+\sqrt{10}) - \ln(2+\sqrt{5})$, I don't know the correct answer, the website just says it's wrong.

Comment: I've got $\pm\left(\frac{15}{2}+\frac{9}{4}\pi\right)$ with wolfram alpha ($\pm$ because I don't know which way would you like to integrate). Did you change the functions as well? $P(x,y)=y=\sinh(t)$, $Q(x,y)=xy-9\frac{y^2}{x}=3\cosh(t)\sinh(t)-3\frac{\sinh^2(t)}{\cosh(t)}$

Comment: Both of your answers are wrong according to this site :S

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with it. Can you find any error in the computation? We might need to wait for @Salahamam_ Fatima

Comment: No, I don't see any error. I've computed it 3 times now. Yeah hopefully someone will straighten things out soon.

Comment: @Parseval Is the vector field $F(x,y)=(x,...)$ or $(y,...)$?

Comment: @Parseval I'm going to make an answer, because it would be too long for a comment.

Comment: It's $y$, sorry about that. Thank you!

Comment: @Parseval It's done, I only need to substitute the correct values of $t$, but I wanted to post the answer before that to let you see it. I'm gonna calculate it now.